# merge ajaxform with ajax to upload image

Tags: ajax

I try to create upload photos in my nodejs site.
I used this code to choose file and upload the image:

```
 var fileData = null;

        function loadFile() {
            var preview = document.querySelector('file');
            var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
            var reader  = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
                fileData = file;
            }
            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }

        function uploadFile() {
            data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', fileData);

            $.ajax({
              url: "/post_pdf/",
              type: "POST",
              data: data,
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              success: function(data) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Result: Upload successful';
              },
              error: function(e) {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Result: Error occurred: ' + e.message;
              }
            });
        }
```

With loadfile funcion i choose my image, and with Uploadfile function i upload the image with ajax.
if i use it alone its work perfect and upload the image to the location.
but when i try to add this code to my code, it make alot of errors.
in my code i send to back end all the forms in the pug file:

```
$('#account-form').ajaxForm({
    error : function(e){
        if (e.responseText == 'title-empty'){
            av.showInvalidTitle();
        }
    },
    success : function(responseText, status, xhr, $form){
        if (status == 'success')
        {
            $('.modal-alert').modal('show');
            console.log(responseText)
        }}
});
```

i try to merge the ajaxform with the ajax but when i merege the formdata or i send in ajaxform the data of the file is send error.
how can i merge the codes?
thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Yogesh Patel
when i use this code:

```
$('#account-form-btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    let form = $("#account-form");
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: new FormData(form[0]),
        error: function (e) {
            if (e.responseText == 'title-empty') {
                av.showInvalidTitle();
            }
        },
        success: function (responseText, status, xhr, $form) {
            if (status == 'success') {
                $('.modal-alert').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

for some reason it sends the values to "routes" three times.
and it doesn't catch the erorrs or success.
and it sends me to a white window with the value of the callback.
if needed, i can send the function that gets the values and returns them (app.post).

Answer (score 1):

Try to submit form it will submit form with your image.

```
  let form = $("#form_id");
            $.ajax({
                url : $(form).attr("action"),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                data: new FormData(form[0]),
                success:function(data){

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, e) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: How can i add to this formfata my data of my file. I edited the posr i have mistake in upload function..

Comment: If you want to submit all data along with all files you don't have to change anything use this, it will post all data and files to your server automatically.

Comment: i posted a new code that i tried, please take a look. thank you.